# Why is my computer not starting when I select start Windows normally?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Anytime I turn my laptop on, it gives me options to choose, either between:

- launch the startup repair or
- start the windows normally

It always says their recommendation was to choose startup repair. So I chose it one day and since then when I choose start windows normally, it never works. It just takes a long time and restarts again.

Is it because I chose startup repair only once?

Comment: Did the repair process fail by chance?

Comment: Are you gracefully shutting down the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a failed startup recovery, you should now boot into the installation disk of windows (i'm assuming it's 7) and enter the reparation menu, then:
- First try the startup repair from there, or
- Second run the "command prompt" and run a chkdsk [volume]: /r (ej: chkdsk C: /r)

If you are always getting the screen to launch the startup repair as you said, it would seem the disk has some bad sectors, so the chkdsk should mark them.